# how to remove space between two strings in sql

Tags: sql

I have a query

```
CONVERT(CHAR(4), A.effort_date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), A.effort_date, 120) as Month
```

The result shows `Jun 2014`.

But I want to show `Jun2014`.

Have tried replace, `ltrim`, `rtrim` nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions please?

`A.effort_date` format is `2014-06-30` in sql table.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (convert, ltrim etc are product specific functions.)

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. Both in text formatted as table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you are using MSSQL, which convert format `100` is `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`

you can try

```
convert(char(3), A.effort_date, 100) + convert(char(4), A.effort_date, 120) as Month
```

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL server demo:

```
select LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,getdate()),3) + DATENAME(YEAR,getdate()) as Month
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use *varchar()* to convert data type

```
 varchar(4)
```